# Declaring composite generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to declare a class that use generic structure embedded in another generic one.
The code I have is:

```
private class Pair<TKey, Value<TKey, TValue>>
```

where Value is defined as

```
private class Value<TKey, TValue>
```

The error I get is an unexpected token on the innermost comma in

```
Pair<TKey, Value<TKey, TValue>>
```

How can I make the compiler accept it? I can't really figure it out.

Comment: The error is "Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type". You cannot pass a type (Value) where you should pass an identifier (example T)

Comment: I suppose you are looking for `private class Pair<TKey, TValue> where TValue : Value<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think that would be right. That force `TValue` to be a [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) which I don't think the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid.  Think for a moment about what this would mean....

> Pair is a generic type that takes one type we'll call TKey, and another generic type that's actually a class

That doesn't really make sense.

You probably want something like

```
private class Pair<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Value<TKey, TValue> _value = new Value<TKey, TValue>();
}
```